# Serialize some string values in a Dictionary as integers

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Currently my `Dictionary<string, string>` is serialized as:

```
{
    "Uri" : "/site/Default.aspx",
    "time-taken" : "232"
}
```

I would like Json.net to serialize it as

```
{
    "Uri" : "/site/Default.aspx",
    "time-taken" : 232
}
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this with Json.net? I don't want to make a new class with the correct types instead of the Dictionary since the keys are many and may change. I know the keys that will be `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would just make a helper method that copied the data from a dictionary to a `JObject` like this:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string SerializeDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict, IEnumerable<string> intKeys)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            int intValue;
            if (intKeys.Contains(kvp.Key) && int.TryParse(kvp.Value, out intValue))
                obj.Add(kvp.Key, intValue);
            else
                obj.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        return obj.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("AnInt", "123");
dict.Add("AString", "abc");
dict.Add("AnotherInt", "456");
dict.Add("KeepThisAsString", "789");
dict.Add("NotAnInt", "xyz");

var intKeys = new string[] { "AnInt", "AnotherInt" };

string json = JsonHelper.SerializeDictionary(dict, intKeys);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "AnInt": 123,
  "AString": "abc",
  "AnotherInt": 456,
  "KeepThisAsString": "789",
  "NotAnInt": "xyz"
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xdnnb0

Comment: Are the numbers in the dictionary in localized or invariant format?  If invariant, [`Int32.TryParse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be used.